# How to count the current consecutive 0 in the Dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a Dataframe with a column called `No.`. I need to count the number of consecutive 0s in column  `No.`. For example, the first 0 is recorded as 1, and the second 0 is recorded as 2. If it encounters 1, the counter is cleared. And save the result in the column `count`.

what should I do?

An example of my Dataframe is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(2021)
a = np.random.randint(0, 2, 20)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['No.'])
print(df)
```

```
     No.
0     0
1     1
2     1
3     0
4     1
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     1
9     0
10    1
11    1
12    1
13    1
14    0
15    0
16    0
17    0
18    0
19    0
```

The result I need:

```
    No. count
0   0   1
1   1   0
2   1   0
3   0   1
4   1   0
5   0   1
6   0   2
7   0   3
8   1   0
9   0   1
10  1   0
11  1   0
12  1   0
13  1   0
14  0   1
15  0   2
16  0   3
17  0   4
18  0   5
19  0   6
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my question? Get vote down again.

Comment: I believe this question is missing your attempt at solving the problem yourself.

Comment: @HenryEcker Got it , I will add my own try next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate pseudo-groups with [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and then generate within-group counters with [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
groups = df['No.'].ne(0).cumsum()
df['count'] = df['No.'].eq(0).groupby(groups).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
    No.  count
0     0      1
1     1      0
2     1      0
3     0      1
4     1      0
5     0      1
6     0      2
7     0      3
8     1      0
9     0      1
10    1      0
11    1      0
12    1      0
13    1      0
14    0      1
15    0      2
16    0      3
17    0      4
18    0      5
19    0      6
```